# How to create view from ST_ConvexHull

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatialite, convex-hull

I have a simple SpatiaLite DB containing one table with point features. I would like to generate a Minimum Convex Hull around that features. I could do that easily with one of the Convex Hull tools from GDAL/SAGA/GRASS/R-Script... from processing toolbox. But I would like to have a dynamic SQL solution. So every time a new point feature is added, the Convex Hull should automatically be updated. So I thought about a SQL-View:

I tried around following this instructions: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html

```
CREATE VIEW birdsmcp AS 
SELECT 
  ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)) 
FROM birds GROUP BY bird;
```

I get a table, but no geometry. What do I have to do to get shapes as a result? I'm not very familiar with SQL queries.

EDIT: Thats my result in QGIS DB-Manager:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that you don't get a geometry back?

Comment: There is no Preview available. See my EDIT please

Comment: what do you see under the table view? and do you see anything if you add the view to the canvas? I managed to see similar behaviour on a virtual scratch point layer (which uses spatialite, I think) but was able to see it on adding to the canvas.

Comment: You might need an integer field added.  Not sure if that is why you don't see the preview, but I think without an integer key field, QGIS sometimes has trouble rendering.  Also I'm confused your workflow.  Did you create your view in PostGIS  and then export to spatial lite, or are you doing some sort of linking from PostGIS to SpatialIte or something else.  I would first start with trying to view the PostGIS view to confirm it works,

Comment: First, Can you clarify if your question addresses Spatialite or PostGIS? (They work differently regarding spatial views)

Comment: I wrote my question incomprehensible (I updated it again). I use SpatiaLite and want to create a view from that SpatiaLite DB, not PostGIS.

Comment: I don't know much about Spatial Lite, but in general it is a good idea to put some kind of id (primary key) column into anything you generate. A shp file, produced like this, will show blank. So, add a `row_number() over() as id` to your select for starters. Also, trying to view things in GUIs can be difficult, especially if they are large binary fields. To prove something is there, try wrapping in ST_Centroid, or ST_NPoints or some other function that will return a short, human readable value.

Comment: You could try something like this:
`CREATE VIEW birdsmcp AS 
SELECT 
  row_number() over() as id, 
  bird,
  ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)) 
FROM birds GROUP BY bird;`

Then you have an ID and even the name of the bird. @MAP Does this work?

Comment: If I use your Querry in the QGIS DB-Manager , I got an error: 'near "(": syntax error'

Comment: I think you can't create a spatialite view with a different geometry type from the layer it's referencing from? So for example you can't create a polygon view when the source has point geometry